# is spyware blaster not useful when using a portable browser?

Tags: spyware

I'm using portable google chrome and portable firefox. 
Is there anyway that spyware blaster could detect my browser in order to protect it if im using a portable app.

Comment: Good question, I know that CCleaner needs modifications in order to scan them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a forum post](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showpost.php?p=1200223&postcount=2) on how to set it up for portable Firefox:

> How to:
>
> 1. Create the following folder:
>
>    Documents and Settings(Your user)\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox
> 2. Create new text file with the following:
>
>    [General] StartWithLastProfile=1
>
>    [Profile0] Name=Default IsRelative=0
>      Path=C:\Tamed\FirefoxPortable\Data\profile  Default=1
>
>    (Set the path to your portable
>      version)
> 3. Save text file as profiles.ini in the folder you created - D:\Documents
>      and Settings(Your user)\Application
>      Data\Mozilla\Firefox
>
> Now start SpyWareBlaster again

I guess SpyWareBlaster searches for profiles.ini files to see if it should scan it, so you can go and create a likewise file for portable Chrome.

Answer (score -1):

Spyware blaster add  Wanterfox

①Create folder

%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox
C:\Users--user Name--\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox

②New file

profiles.ini

---

[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=Default
IsRelative=0
Path=C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Waterfox\Profiles\ubnhhn7t.default
Default=1

[Profile2]
Name=Default User
IsRelative=0
Path=C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Waterfox\Profiles\cpbunvhk.68-edition-default

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obdPj.jpg)